# Edit connection string at interface (EntityFramework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am writing an application on WPF (MVVM) using the Entity Framework (DataBase first). I want users to set the server name through interface, tell me how to do it please. If I pass the variable from the settings, I get a: `System.ArgumentException keyword not supported 'data source'`.

```
 using (var db = new PronetsDataBaseEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString)) { ...}
```

The ConnectionString is the same as it generated EntityFramework

```
(metadata=res://*/Data.PronetsDB.csdl|res://*/Data.PronetsDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.PronetsDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=DESKTOP-D6JRGFG\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PronetsDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework")
```

Constructor on Entity:

```
public PronetsDataBaseEntities(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection string must only be the part after "provider connection string=", so in your case: "data source=DESKTOP-D6JRGFG\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PronetsDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"

Comment: I tried it before this I ask. This is not work. System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: The context is used in Code First mode with code generated from an .edmx file for developing Database First or Model First.

Comment: did you omit the quotation marks in the string itself?

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem of creating my connection method